# Executing a Yii module without a route

Tags: php, yii, url-routing, clean-urls

I have a module that is named article. It exists in the collowing folder:

```
- protected
      - modules
           - article
                 - controllers
                   ArticleController.php
                 - views
                       -article
             articleModule.php
```

Since I am making a CMS. I have chosen not to use direct links to controllers or actions. This means a call to example.com/article/article/index. Would not work. Since the CMS treats an url request as a page. (So it looks for a page called 'index' with a parents 'article' and 'article'. Such a page does not exist.

The CMS loads blocks for a valid page and for one of this blocks I want to execute the article module. I tried using

```
Yii::app()->runController($route).
```

However for this you need a route.

Is it possible to run a module like this so that the module works the same as going to the url example.com/article/article ?

Or if that is not possible. How do I setup the Url Manager so that it can handle pages?. With Clean Urls. Here are some examples:

```
example.com/join_us  
example.com/join_us/contact 
example.com/news/ 
example.com/countries/us/healthcare
```

The above are pages that the user can create and change. I have wrestled with this for a long time. Normally it would be an easy thing. But Yii makes it very hard. Mostly because a controller or module is linked to going to a route.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. Should all URLs be served from one action only (in `modules/article`)? If not, which URLs should be excluded?

Comment: Show us your urlManager rules

Comment: @MichaelHärtl Harti
standard index action and all other actions by using get params

Comment: @Soju, Currently I have written everything to a pageController that handles all clean url. 
`code`
    'urlManager'=>array(
       'urlFormat'=>'path',
       'showScriptName'=>false,

       'rules'=>array(
    '(.*)'=>'page/index',
        ),
    ),

Otherwise if I fill in a self made clean url it will be treated as a <controller> <action> type. But such a module or controller doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your main configuration:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'caseSensitive'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        'gii'=>'gii',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>', 
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
    ),
),
```

And this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

If a directory or a file exists, use it directly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

...otherwise forward it to `index.php`:

```
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: @Virtlink why did you rate down my answer

Comment: Yes, why would I? I don't know, must be someone else. I only edited it.

Comment: @Virtlink Thanks for the suggestion. A link like about_us however now goes to an  action in the siteController. And for every page I need to make an action in siteController now. Also subpages don't work like join_us/contact. Could you explain abit about the idea of this. Again thanks for the reply. What i try to achieve is to run module if they exists in that folder. Otherwise send a url and sub url to a standard controller let's say siteController. That checks if it's a valid page. That is the idea I currently have.

Comment: update: I changed the last line to  `'<action>'=>'page/index'`. It seems to work for all first level parent urls, but not for any 2nd, 3th and onwards.

Interesting is that the 3 standard Yii controller action rule
`'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'` seems to be invocated first and then the last 4th action rule. The third one is important but it does seem to conflict with my previous single rule of `'(.*)'=>'page/index'`. If I place this single rule after the 3th controller action rule.

Comment: @Minahalmon You'll have to ask Gunnit, the writer of the post. I only clarified it.

Comment: @gunnit thanks for the reply. Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow. And thanks Virtlink for the explanation tips. So far I have come far. But I can't say it's sovled yet. This worked well
   `'<action>'=>'page/index',`

But the 2nd and 3th sub level links don't work. Like `example.com/about_us/countries/us`. As you can see it has at least 3 levels. I tried adding the following:

`'<action><action>'=>'page/index',`
    
In an attempt to see if it worked but it gives an error. I am not completely new to url rewriting but I am not sure how to tags and terms with Yii Url Manager.

Answer (score 1):

You could route everything to article controller. Yii uses rules from in order from top to bottom, so first define some specific rules, and in the end something like catch-all rule. This should work:

```
// Url manager rules
// Some of example non-article rules
'login' => 'userModule/user/login'
'logout' => 'userModule/user/login'
// Below regex rule catch any string and pass it to $_GET['ariticlePath'] 
// and executes action `article` of controller `article` of module `article` 
'<ariticlePath:.+>' => 'article/article/article'
```

In article action you can do whatever you want with passed `$_GET['ariticlePath']`.

**SIDE NOTE**: To avoid double indexing of content i recommend using meta `canonical`, so some possibly bogus urls with query string or whatever some users might enter, will not be treated as duplicated content by google.

**EDIT:** As soju sugested, `articlePath` can also be bound as action param:

```
...
public function actionArticle($articlePath)
...
```

Comment: +1, but don't use `$_GET['articlePath']`, you just have to add `$articlePath` param to your controller action function

Comment: Nice, seem to be a new feature since i was reading fundamentals:)

Comment: Still truggling to get his to work. I have put in the 3 above write rules. And removed my (.*) rule to pageController. But it goes to the login page now. Since that is the first rules it comes by. I tried filling in index.php/?articlepath=get. But now it goes to standard Yii welcome view handled by siteController